# onShowFileChooser with internal storage returns permission denied

Tags: android, camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am creating an android application that uses a webview, but the webview needs access to images from the Camera. I use the following code to create the image file and it passes the path to the camera later on (in onShowFileChooser?).

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
    if(storageDir.mkdirs())
        Log.d(TAG, "Unable to create dir" + storageDir);
    File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg",);
    Log.d(TAG, "Storage: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    return imageFile;
}
```

Now the above code will generate a permission denied by the camera. This file will be deleted as soon as the application dies, and as I understand it (for security reasons), another application will not be able to browse my directory and thus wont know if that file exists unless it was passed directly.

However, when I get the camera to launch, it wont save the file. It throws a FileNotFound exception with (Permission Denied).

```
04-10 21:00:44.818  22637-22637/? W/CAM_PhotoModule﹕ exception saving result to URI: file:///data/data/<package-name>/files/JPEG_20150410_210024_.jpg
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
```

How can I get the camera to write to that specific file? (Note, I don't want to use external media at all, to prevent another app from possibly intercepting the file, or if the mobile device doesn't have external memory).

Another note: This is coming from a fragment (thus the getActivity().getFilesDir()).

Any help is appreciated. I looked for an answer online and couldn't find one, I'd just like a final statement of "It can't be done" if it seriously can't be done.

Comment: for certainty can you please post the error?

Comment: 04-10 21:00:44.818  22637-22637/? W/CAM_PhotoModule﹕ exception saving result to URI: file:///data/data/<package>/files/JPEG_20150410_210024_.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied

Comment: Negative @nitzrobotkoder. I'm guessing not possible